# RPI 4 Vilros black screen on boot

Tags: pi-4

I know lots of articles about black screen on boot. I bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VFCB192) RPi4 kit from Amazon. Built the kit with no issue, plugged it into my 34" LG monitor, which supports 1080p along with a USB keyboard, booted up and black screen. Per their instructions I should get a screen config selection option. Checking the contents of the USB drive, I don't see a boot/ directory or a start.elf file. I've tried different HDMI ports with no difference in behavior. I also checked my router's DHCP lease list and the device is not getting an IP. I'm hesitant to rebuild the SD card being that I can read all the files on it.

Any suggestions on what I can do short of rebuilding the  OS?

Thanks!

Comment: *contents of the USB drive* - what USB drive? that kit comes with an SD card, and some weird looking UDB / SD adapter (at least I think that's what that is) - don't use that in a pi 4 - just stick the sd card in the sd card slot on the pi

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a micro SD card in a USB micro SD reader. I can plug the reader and the card into my desktop and read the contents. On the Pi4, I've plugged the reader into one of the USB ports. The Pi4 SD slots appear to be full size, not micro.

Answer (score 0):

There's a microSD card reader on the RPi4 motherboard. It's on the bottom... after putting the card in the MSD slot and the unit boots up just fine.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.